# Objects of mesh render are overlayed by UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good day. I need that objects of mesh render (puzzles) overlay UI when user pick them. But I don't know how to accomplish that. I have this now:

[image: Puzzles overlayed by UI]

It's the problem.

I have this configuration of canvas:

[image]

Puzzles belong to **Puzzle** layer, and all UI components to **UI** layer. 
And this is settings of puzzle elemnt:

[image: Puzzle's settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sorting Layers

This img shows example on the particle system. If you need to set sorting layer on another objects in editor -- you need some additional asset. Also you can change sorting layer for any UI element programmaly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this topic,](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/876698/ui-46-is-there-a-way-to-render-models-over-the-ui.html) it explains this subject pretty clearly, and I think it's the only way to achieve what you want:

> requirement to do this is that the UI needs to be Screen Space - Camera not Screen Space - Overlay. Then you can create GameObjects with the model add a RectTransform and position them inside the hierarchy of your UI.

Let know if this helps.

Comment: @AdamRoszyk I saw this topic, I tried this. As you can see on second screen on canvas, which belongs to UI have Screen Space - Camera and my puzzle pieces are part of UI hierarchy. But It doesnt work. But I don't change Z coordinates by myself. May be I should?